# If the geodesic curvature of a simple closed spherical curve is monotonic, then it is constant

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curves, surfaces

Let $\gamma$ be a simple closed curve in the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{2} \subset \mathbb{R}^{3}$. I wish to understand how the property of being simple and closed affects the geodesic curvature of $\gamma$.

Clearly, the geodesic curvature can be constant (e.g., geodesics are simple and closed). In general, I suppose that being simple and closed must result in a minimum number of critical points of the geodesic curvature. In fact, my question is the following. If the geodesic curvature $\kappa_{g}$ of $\gamma$ is nonconstant, does it then follow that its derivative $\kappa_{g}'$ changes sign at least once?

Hints on how to prove/disprove this statement would also be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by "**its** derivative"?

Comment: At the end of the loop the curvature is back to its initial value, hence...

Comment: @LeeMosher I mean the derivative of the geodesic curvature with respect to the curve parameter

Comment: In fact, this is a question about continuous function on the circle: either it is constant or either it has a maximum and a minimum.

Comment: @ MK7: Intuitively. if $\kappa_g$ is constant then it is a small circle. If monotonous say $\kappa_g = a \cdot s + b $ then it results in a Cornu spiral like behavior that does not close unless $a=0$

Comment: Just to make sure you realize: Every latitude circle is a curve of constant geodesic curvature — the geodesics being a special case.

Comment: I forgot to add ... So *every* circle on the sphere is a curve of constant geodesic curvature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me assume that $\gamma : S^1 \to S^2$ is smooth, and that a transverse orientation of $\gamma$ has been chosen. The geodesic curvature is therefore defined as a smooth function $\kappa_\gamma : S^1 \mapsto \mathbb R$.

If the geodesic curvature is not constant, there are points $c,C \in \gamma$ at which $\kappa_\gamma(c) < \kappa_\gamma(C)$.

Applying the Mean Value Theorem, in the arc of $\gamma$ from $c$ to $C$ there is a point $d_+ \in \gamma$ where $\kappa'_\gamma(d_+) > 0$, and in the opposite arc from $C$ to $c$ there is a point $d_- \in \gamma$ where $\kappa'_\gamma(d_-) < 0$. The function $\kappa'_\gamma$ must therefore change from positive to negative in the arc of $\gamma$ from $d_+$ to $d_-$, and back again from negative to positive in the opposite arc from $d_-$ to $d_+$.

Comment: This is a fine answer. But it should be noted that this result doesn't really have anything to do with geodesic curvature, or $S^2$, or even differentiability. If $f:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb R$ is a continuous monotone function such that $f(0) = f(2\pi)$, then $f$ is constant. Once you've verified this, just apply it to $f(t) = \kappa_\gamma( e^{it})$.